# Disabling fields on Bills and Adjustments doesn't seem to work

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom dropdown field on Bills and Adjustments which I want to determine when to disable specific fields on the screen.  I'm using the following logic, which doesn't seem to work (the commented lines didn't work either).  I've set the commitchanges to true on the user field - and I've stepped through the code to make sure it's getting hit:

```
    protected virtual void APInvoice_UsrPOStatus_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        var apr = (APRegister)e.Row;
        if (apr == null) return;

        var aprext = PXCache<APRegister>.GetExtension<APRegisterExt>(apr);
        if (aprext == null) return;

        if (aprext.UsrPOstatus != "Open")
        {
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APRegister.docType>(sender, apr, false);
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APRegister.refNbr>(sender, apr, false);
            //PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APInvoice.docType>(Base.Document.Cache, null, false);  //(OpenSourceDataDetail.Cache, null, true);
            //PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APInvoice.refNbr>(Base.Document.Cache, null, false);
        }
    }
```

I get no errors, but nothing happens.  Is it not possible to disable these fields?

I'm also not sure whether to use APInvoice or APRegister for these statements.

Comment: APInvoice inherits from APRegister. I'd go for APInvoice to follow the base graph and avoid type casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a field enabled state and visibility can't be changed it's usually because a later event overrides your changes.

The base graph of the graph extension you're working on (APInvoiceEntry) calls SetEnabled on these fields in the APInvoice_RowSelected event.

To override these calls you should override the same event in your extension, then your event handler will be the last one executed.

```
protected virtual void APInvoice_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
  APInvoice apInvoice = e.Row as APInvoice;

  if (apInvoice == null)
  {
    return;
  }

  PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APInvoice.docType>(cache, apInvoice, false);
  PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APInvoice.refNbr>(cache, apInvoice, false);
}
```